# Javascript hide with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got some troubles with setTimeOut, i want to delay the hide of the submenu, but its not working at all.. :-(

I put the working line inside comments.  What i have done wrong?

```
        $('ul.menu').find('li').mouseover(function() {
           $(this).children('ul, .mega-menu').css('display','block');

        }).mouseout(function() {
           setTimeout(this.children('ul, .mega-menu').style.display="none",4000); 
           /* $(this).children('ul, .mega-menu').css('display','none'); */
        });
```

Thanks for any help or ideas!

Comment: try `setTimeout(this.children('ul, .mega-menu').hide(4000);`

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){ this.children('ul, .mega-menu').style.display="none"}, 4000);`

Comment: you just needed to pass an anon callback function to setTimeout method

Comment: @MayankVadiya: That's not even valid JavaScript....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this to hide with delay:-

```
$('ul.menu').find('li').delay(4000).fadeOut();
```

> This will wait for 4 sec then hide

To show use this:-

```
$('ul.menu').find('li').delay(6000).fadeIn();
```

So you can write like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('ul.menu').find('li').hover(function() {
     var $megamenu = $(this).children('ul, .mega-menu'); 
     $megamenu.show();   
  },function() {
    var $megamenu = $(this).children('ul, .mega-menu');  
    $megamenu.delay(4000).fadeOut(); 
 });
});
```

you can also use `fadeOut(1000)` for animation effect.

If you want to use `setTimeout` you can use `Dave Salomon` answers or this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('ul.menu').find('li').hover(function() {
     var $megamenu = $(this).children('ul, .mega-menu'); 
     $megamenu.show();   
  },function() {
    var $megamenu = $(this).children('ul, .mega-menu');  
    setTimeout(function(){$megamenu.hide()},"4000"); 
 });
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: As much as your answer works and improves on a better way to handle what he was trying to do while sticking in the context of jquery, this doesn't answer what he did wrong when using setTimeout, which is what he asked.

Comment: Awesome! Just so original questioner or someone searching knows why it didn't work the way they tried. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('ul.menu').find('li').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children('ul, .mega-menu').show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children('ul, .mega-menu').hide(4000);     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass either a function (and not calling it) or code to `setTimeout`'s first parameter. Try:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function(){
    that.children('ul, .mega-menu').style.display="none";
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scope in your `setTimeout(function(){...});` isn't the same as the rest of the method. i.e. `this` is different.

Also, your code is a bit wonky.

```
$('ul.menu').find('li').mouseover(function() {
    var $submenu = $(this).children('ul, .mega-menu');
    $submenu.css('display','block');
}).mouseout(function() {
    var $submenu = $(this).children('ul, .mega-menu');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $submenu.hide();
    }, 4000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/hLk0s0bd/